# What is the meaning of this code in php tag --> <?php } ?>

Tags: php

Everytime i search for the code, I always encountered this code, an opening tag of php, without any php code inside, but only a closed curly bracket and ends with an ending tag of php. To be more understandable this is the code: And this code works perfectly fine, and Im curious what function it contributes to the whole code?

This is the code:

```
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: There is likely another set of PHP tags above it in the code with the opening curly bracket.

Comment: There must be a curly bracket `{` above this code. Think, they then simply close the PHP and add some HTML, and to close the curly bracket section again, they simply open a new PHP tag, close the bracket and end the PHP section again.

Comment: @Twinfriends, I think you're right. Thanks for answering my question. Now I am getting more knowledgeable. How can i vote your answer? I think I cant vote yours because I have only 1 reputation, Am i right?

Comment: You can do `<?php if ($condition) { ?><p>Some HTML paragraph outside PHP</p><?php } ?>`, which in a lot of cases becomes more readable.

Comment: @Saffron Exactly, you haven't enough reputation. But since its only a comment I wrote, its not really worth voting it anyway. I won't get any reputation of it or something. Its only that others see, that my comment has some relevance. You can only upvote & accept answers, and then the autor of the answer will get some reputation. I don't think its really worth posting an answer for this kind of question, since its totally enough to answer you in a comment. Anyways, thanks you want to upvote me. Always glad if I could help! :) The upvote is in my heart :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by [Twinfriends](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5740849/twinfriends):

> There must be a curly bracket **{** above this code. Think, they then simply close the PHP and add some HTML, and to close the curly bracket section again, they simply open a new PHP tag, close the bracket and end the PHP section again.